# Slide an image into the page when the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, sliding

I am trying to slide an image into the page when the page is loaded, I have the script working fine however when the image hasn't been chached it loads the image first, then executes the script. I have tried to preload the images but still am getting the glich.

Here is a testing link: http://luvly.co.nz/space/akatarawa-road.html

And here is the scripts I have been dealing with:

preload

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
            this.each(function(){
                $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
            });
        }

        // Usage:

        $(['images/aka/aka1.2.jpg',
            'images/aka/aka2.jpg',
            'images/aka/aka3.jpg',
            'images/aka/aka4.jpg',
            'images/aka/aka5.jpg',
            'images/aka/aka6.jpg', 
            'images/aka/aka7.jpg', 
            'images/aka/aka8.jpg', 
            'images/aka/aka9.jpg', 
            'images/aka/aka10.jpg']).preload();
```

Slider:

```
$(function() {
  $("#1-slide").one('load', function () {
    $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
  }).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
});
```

Also I know I shouldn't be using a number to start an ID but it is just for testing purposes at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to ensure that image is loaded before the running of the script, so try something like the following:

```
<body>
<img src=image1.jpg" style="display:none" />
....
Your script calling
```

This solution depends on calling images you want to be in the slide first, so it downloaded in the cache before running the script. so it will be cached first

Comment: Cool, I have tried this however doesn;t seem to be able to overright the display:none;??

Comment: @Spade The display:none is only meant by the img tag, it does not affect the visibility of the image itself inside any other contest